# Spherical harmonics expansion of $f(\theta, \phi) = \sin{\theta} \left| \cos{\phi} \right|$

Tags: functions, special-functions, spherical-coordinates, spherical-harmonics

I am trying to expand in spherical harmonics the following real function:

$f(\theta, \phi) = \sin{\theta} \left| \cos{\phi} \right|$

by applying the definition of the spherical harmonics expansion it is possible to write

$f(\theta, \phi) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-k}^{k} f_{k \, m} Y_{k \, m}^{*}$

where $Y_{k \, m}^{*} $ are spherical harmonics.

The coefficients $f_{k \, m}$ are then given by:

$f_{k \, m}= \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(\theta, \phi) \, \sin{\theta}\,  Y_{k \, m}^{*}\, d\phi \, d\theta$

with $Y_{k \, m}^{*}$

until now here everything is fine.
However, when I carry out the integration above (with mathematica) to compute the coefficients $f_{k \, m}$ i found that $\, f_{k \, m} = f_{k \, -m}$.

But, in the following paper the authors are expanding exactly the same function: https://doi.org/10.1017/jfm.2015.129 (Pag 11 and 12; Eq 3.5-3.9)

In fact, the authors claim that the terms $f_{k \, m}$ with $m<0$ vanish.

I am abit clueless, despite the expansion step seems straightforward to me, I am not sure I am doing it correctly.

(If you can't access the paper here's a screenshot of that part):

### Derivation by the authors:

[image]

[...]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, it does look like an error. What they appear to be doing is using $e^{\pm im\phi} = \cos{m\phi}\pm i\sin{\phi}$ to expand in terms of sines and cosines for $m\geq 0$ instead of $e^{im\theta}$ for both positive and negative $m$. After all, $\cos{(-m\phi)}=\cos{m\phi}$ and $P^{-m}_k(x) \propto P^m_k(x)$, so the integral with a negative $m$ is proportional to that with a positive $m$. The justification should be that $P_k^m(\cos{\theta})\cos{m\phi}$ and $P_k^m(\cos{\theta})\sin{m\phi}$ for $0 \leq m \leq k$ form a basis, just as $P_k^m(\cos{\theta})e^{im\phi}$ for $-k \leq m \leq k$ do.

Comment: mmm from what I understand is that we are choosing different basis for the expansion. Do you mean that, the two expansions of $\sin{\theta} \left| \cos{\phi} \right|$ defined either with spherical harmonics (as I did) and by Eq. 3.7 in the paper are the same?

Comment: They should produce the same answer, although in slightly different basis (note that the basis in terms of sines and cosines is not orthonormal until rescaled, so some of the constants will be different). You'll have to put your $\pm m$ terms together to get the cosines.